# Second time doing a Web Request doesn't work

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have been trying to do some http requests in C#. First time doing http request GET it worked, but the second time it didn't work and it returned null, can someone please help?

```cs
private static dynamic WebRequestGET(Uri url)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
                var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                var reader = new StreamReader(webStream);
                var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic jsonData = JObject.Parse(data);
                request.Abort();
                webResponse.Close();
                webStream.Close();
                return jsonData;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                var window = GetConsoleWindow();
                ShowWindow(window, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occured while fetching data, if error will occur again please create issue on github{Environment.NewLine}{e.Message}");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Application.Exit();
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: ```string placeIdS = (string)WebRequestGET(url1)["PlaceId"];
string gameId = (string)WebRequestGET(url1)["GameId"];
long placeId = long.Parse(placeIdS);```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String

Comment: Just found out that it was problem of the API, it returned null values 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this to make the get request. You might need to add restsharp using nuget.

```
using RestSharp;
// ^^ put at top of file
var client = new RestClient("https://www.google.com");
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.Get;
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
// change this to whatever you want ^^
```

I'd also recommend postman.com since it can generate the code for you.

Comment: Just as a recommendation. I’d probably move away from rest sharp and just use the native HttpClient. RestSharp uses this under the hood now anyway and doesn’t really add anything useful anymore